# Telegram [BOT] My Bot Is Not Responding In Groups But It Works Fine In Individual Chats [JAVA]

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

Commands.java Source Code :

```
import java.util.Random;

import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendPhoto;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.methods.send.SendSticker;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException;


public class Commands extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    
    public final static String PREFIX = "/";
    public static String []getMessage;
    public static long chatId;
    public static int msgId;
    public static String member;

    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        
          String []Message = update.getMessage().getText().split("\\s+");
          long chat_id = update.getMessage().getChat().getId();
          int msg_id = update.getMessage().getMessageId();
          String mem = update.getMessage().getChat().getUserName().toString();
          
          getMessage = Message;
          chatId = chat_id;
          msgId = msg_id;
          member = mem;
          
          System.out.println(Commands.chatId);
          System.out.println(chat_id);

          if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
           
            if(getMessage[0].equalsIgnoreCase(PREFIX+"diss")) {
                Diss();
            }
        
            if(getMessage[0].equalsIgnoreCase(PREFIX+"waifu")) {
                Waifu();
            }
        
            if(getMessage[0].equalsIgnoreCase(PREFIX+"Developer")) {
                Developer();
            }
        
            if(getMessage[0].equalsIgnoreCase(PREFIX+"say")) {
                Say();
            }
        
            if(getMessage[0].equalsIgnoreCase(PREFIX+"iq")) {
                IQ();
            }
        
            if(getMessage[0].equalsIgnoreCase(PREFIX+"convert")) {
                Convert();
            }
        
            if(getMessage[0].equalsIgnoreCase(PREFIX+"gravitational")) {
                Gravitational();
            }
        
            if(getMessage[0].equalsIgnoreCase(PREFIX+"avogadro")) {
                avogadro();
            }
        
            if(getMessage[0].equalsIgnoreCase(PREFIX+"planck")) {
                Planck();
            }
        
            if(getMessage[0].equalsIgnoreCase(PREFIX+"epsilon")) {
                Epsilon();
            }
            
            BasicAbility();
            new SaikatBOTGame().onUpdateReceived(update);
            
            
    }
          
          
        
}

    @Override
       public String getBotUsername() {
           // Return bot username
           // If bot username is @MyAmazingBot, it must return 'MyAmazingBot'
           return "BOTNAME";
       }

       @Override
       public String getBotToken() {
           // Return bot token from BotFather
           return "12345:saikatdas";
       }
  
       public void Waifu() {
           long chat_id = chatId;
           SendPhoto photo = new SendPhoto()
                  .setChatId(chat_id)
                  .setPhoto(waifu());
          
          try {
                execute(photo);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
       
       public String waifu() {
           
           String waifu[] = {
                   "https://pm1.narvii.com/6563/5fa949a47a8a12b3e115ac89b2cd5f5e5acdb9bc_hq.jpg",
                   "https://www.vippng.com/png/detail/238-2382660_tippy-hoodie-anime-girls-anime-girl-cute-anime.png",
                   "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp5114631.jpg",
                   "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/14/79/9d/14799d9779f9b44d7116783ce7121d5f.jpg",
                   "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp3452807.jpg",
                   "https://www.wallpaperup.com/uploads/wallpapers/2016/09/26/1020331/5a94556e430bfbb3d60b5af233521d19-700.jpg",
                   "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a6/38/72/a63872eb3f1d9f8c5691617918cff56e.jpg",
                   "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/da/69/ce/da69ce1b092ff200d63420e50a9e2c1b.jpg",
                   "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/19/12/98/191298926e6a8e02bc05409ee39ebf5c.jpg",
                   "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/bd/38/f2/bd38f2e73ec72fc63af466525f53636d.jpg",
                   "https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp6051017.jpg"
                  
           };
           
           int i = toGenerate(waifu.length);
           
           return waifu[i];
       }
       
       public static int toGenerate(int x) {
            Random generator = new Random();
            int y = generator.nextInt(x);
            
            return y ;
        }
       
       public void avogadro() {
           long chat_id = Commands.chatId;
           int msg_id = Commands.msgId;
           
           SendMessage msg =  new SendMessage()
                   .setChatId(chat_id)
                   .setReplyToMessageId(msg_id)
                   .setText("Avogadro's Constant : 6.022 x 10^23 per mole");
                      
          try {
                execute(msg);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
       
       public void BasicAbility() {
           String []getMessage = Commands.getMessage;
              long chat_id = Commands.chatId;
              int msg_id = Commands.msgId;
               
               if(getMessage[0].equalsIgnoreCase("saikat")) {
                   SendMessage msg = new SendMessage()
                           .setChatId(chat_id)
                           .setReplyToMessageId(msg_id)
                           .setText("Hey, He is My Developer");
                   try {
                    execute(msg);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
               }
              
              for(int i = 0 ; i < getMessage.length; i++) {
                  if(getMessage[i].equalsIgnoreCase("noice") || getMessage[i].equalsIgnoreCase("nice")) {
                     SendMessage msg = new SendMessage()
                             .setChatId(chat_id)
                             .setText("");
                     
                     try {
                        execute(msg);
                    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                        
                     
                  }
              }
              
              if(getMessage[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Hi")||getMessage[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Hello")) {
                  
                  
               SendMessage msg = new SendMessage()
                       .setChatId(chat_id)
                       .setText("Hello "+member);
                                               
               try {
                execute(msg);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              }
                
                for(int i = 0 ; i < getMessage.length; i++) {
                      if(getMessage[i].equalsIgnoreCase("lmao") || getMessage[i].equalsIgnoreCase("lol")) {
                         SendMessage msg = new SendMessage()
                                 .setChatId(chat_id)
                                 .setText("");
                         
                         try {
                            execute(msg);
                        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }                        
                         
                      }
                }
                
                 if(getMessage[0].equalsIgnoreCase("op")||getMessage[0].equalsIgnoreCase("good")) {
                      SendSticker sendSticker = new SendSticker()
                              .setSticker("CAACAgIAAxkBAAL5n171qSxo6eotjBzx3lv--xenwmBbAAIFAQACVp29Crfk_bYORV93GgQ")
                              .setChatId(chat_id);
                      
                      try {
                        execute(sendSticker);
                    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
                  
                  if(getMessage[0].equalsIgnoreCase("ornoob")) {
                      SendMessage msg = new SendMessage()
                               .setChatId(chat_id)
                               .setReplyToMessageId(msg_id)
                               .setText("Lmao !!! Ornoob You Won't Get Mini14   ");
                  
                  try {
                        execute(msg);
                    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
       }
       
       public void Convert() {
           String []getMessage = Commands.getMessage;
           long chat_id = Commands.chatId;
           int msg_id = Commands.msgId;
              
              if(getMessage[1].startsWith("$")) {
                  String value = getMessage[1].substring(1);
                  System.out.print(value);
                  Double USD = Double.valueOf(value);
                  double INR = 75.6029334 * USD;
                  INR = Math.ceil(INR*100)/100;
                  
                  SendMessage message = new SendMessage()
                          .setChatId(chat_id)
                          .setReplyToMessageId(msg_id)
                          .setText("INR Value : Rs."+INR);
                  try {
                    execute(message);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
              
              else if(getMessage[1].startsWith("Rs.")){
                  String value = getMessage[1].substring(3);
                  Double INR = Double.valueOf(value);
                  double USD = INR / 75.6029334;
                  USD = Math.ceil(USD*100)/100;
                  
                  SendMessage message = new SendMessage()
                          .setChatId(chat_id)
                          .setReplyToMessageId(msg_id)
                          .setText("USD Value : $"+USD);
                  try {
                    execute(message);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
       }
       
       public void Developer() {
           long chat_id = Commands.chatId;
           SendMessage msg = new SendMessage()
                   .setChatId(chat_id)
                   .setText("Instagram : instagram.com/@Saikat._\nTelegram : t.me/xSaikat\nGmail : sd.appdeveloping@gmail.com");
          
          try {
                execute(msg);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
       
       public void Diss() {
           String []getMessage = Commands.getMessage;
          long chat_id = Commands.chatId;
           String diss = dissDialogue(getMessage[1]);
                   
                   if(getMessage[1].equalsIgnoreCase("saikat")||getMessage[1].equalsIgnoreCase("eraserhead")) {
                      SendMessage msg = new SendMessage()
                               .setChatId(chat_id)
                               .setText("You Cannot Diss The Developer");
                     try {
                        execute(msg);
                    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                   }
                   else {
                      SendMessage msg = new SendMessage()
                               .setChatId(chat_id)
                               .setText(diss);
                       
                       try {
                        execute(msg);
                    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                   }
        }
       
       public void Epsilon() {
           long chat_id = Commands.chatId;
           int msg_id = Commands.msgId;
              
              SendMessage msg =  new SendMessage()
                       .setChatId(chat_id)
                       .setReplyToMessageId(msg_id)
                       .setText("Epsilon Naught : 8.85 x 10^-12 farads per meter");
                          
              try {
                    execute(msg);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
       }
       
       public void Gravitational() {
           long chat_id = Commands.chatId;
           int msg_id = Commands.msgId;
              
              SendMessage msg =  new SendMessage()
                       .setChatId(chat_id)
                       .setReplyToMessageId(msg_id)
                       .setText("Gravitational Constant : 6.67 x 10^-11 Nm^2/kg^2");
                          
              try {
                    execute(msg);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
       }
       
       public void IQ() {
           String []getMessage = Commands.getMessage;
          long chat_id = Commands.chatId;
           int msg_id = Commands.msgId;
              
              int x = toGenerate(120);
                
             SendMessage msg =  new SendMessage()
                       .setChatId(chat_id)
                       .setReplyToMessageId(msg_id)
                       .setText("WOW !!! "+getMessage[1]+" Your IQ is "+x);
                      
              try {
                execute(msg);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
             
       public void Planck() {
           long chat_id = Commands.chatId;
           int msg_id = Commands.msgId;
              
              SendMessage msg =  new SendMessage()
                       .setChatId(chat_id)
                       .setReplyToMessageId(msg_id)
                       .setText("Planck's Constant : 6.626 x 10^-34 J s");
                          
              try {
                    execute(msg);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
       }
       
       public void Say() {
           String []getMessage = Commands.getMessage;
          long chat_id = Commands.chatId;
           int i = getMessage.length;
                String say = "";
                for(int j = 1 ; j < i ; j++) {
                    say = say + " " + getMessage[j];
                }
                
                SendMessage msg = new SendMessage()
                       .setChatId(chat_id)
                       .setText(say);
                
                try {
                execute(msg);
            } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
       
       public String dissDialogue(String s) {
            String x = "";
            
            switch(toGenerate(9)) {
                case 0 : x = s + ", You Piece Of Shit"; break;
                case 1 : x = s + " Got a Smol PP.."; break;
                case 2 : x = s +", Go Suck Your Own Dick"; break;
                case 3 : x = " My Balls Are More Pretty Than " + s + "'s Face"; break;
                case 4 : x = s +" Eat My Pubic Hairs"; break;
                case 5 : x = s +" Momma Like To Comb My Pubic Hairs"; break;
                case 6 : x = s +", Your Mouth is Filled With My Cum"; break;
                case 7 : x = "I Farted On "+ s + "'s Mouth"; break;
                case 8 : x = s +", Go Jerk Your 2cm Dick"; break;
                case 9 : x = s +"'s Momma Likes To Jerk My Dick"; break;
            }
            return x;
        }
       
    
}
```

Main.java

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.ApiContextInitializer;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.TelegramBotsApi;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Initialize Api Context
      ApiContextInitializer.init();

      // Instantiate Telegram Bots API
      TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();

      // Register our bot
      try {
        botsApi.registerBot(new Commands());
    } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

I Have Checked Privacy Setting Using BotFather And EveryThing Is Fine...
So, Something is Wrong With My Program !!!!

I Have Tried Many Approches But Still It is Not Responding To Commands In Groups
It is Working Fine In Private Chats...

I Dont Know What Wrong With My Program...

Hope You All Can Help Me Out...
Thanks In Advance...

Comment: Looks like you are posting the entire project here?

Comment: No, I Haven't Post The SaikatBOTGame.java

Comment: Well, but a total of 476 LoC seems to be a bit... too much

Comment: Is This causing My Above Mentioned Problem